# Looking for a childrens book from the 70s about kids that build a spaceship

Tags: story-identification

There were a group of kids (3 or 4) and they were joined by a Chinese girl from a well off family. I remember they visited a plant and something about flies buzzing in their brains at the end where she betrayed her shipmates or something. There was something about having 'encoded cards' that they got on the black market.

Comment: Can you recall any other details? Right now, there might not be enough to identify this story.

Comment: only vague details. There was something about having 'encoded cards' that they got on the black market...sadly it was a loooong time ago that I read it!!

Comment: Could you edit any details you can recall (even vaguely) into your question? Questions without sufficient detail *can* get closed, so this will maximize your chance of getting your question answered.

Comment: Try clicking through on the `story-identification` tag to see a list of criteria, but some things you will want to provide include when you read this, where, what language, how long the book might have been, whether there were illustrations, what you remember of the cover, plotlines, etc.

Comment: Your description partially matches Nicolas Fisk's "Starstormers" which came out in 1980, had four kids who built a spaceship (one was Chinese) and involved fighting against semi-sentient "dust" for part of its plot.

Comment: OMG...I think that's it!! thank you so much!!

Answer (score 8):

Your description partially matches Nicolas Fisk's [Starstormers](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/f/nicholas-fisk/starstormers.htm) which came out in 1980 (so the timeline is approximately correct).

- It had four kids who built a spaceship out of a hollowed-out asteroid so they can join their parents in space
- one was a Chinese girl, named *Tsu*
- no flies, but the story involved fighting against semi-sentient "dust" for part of its plot, which was motile and behaved like insects if I remember correctly.